# Degree of polynomial seen as a smooth map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

I need some help with a part of an exercise. Let $P$ be a real polynomial of degree $d$, seen as a map $P:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $d$ is even then the degree of $P$, $degP$, seen as a smooth map is zero and if $d$ is odd, then $degP=\pm1$.

I thought to use the fact that $degP=\sum_{x\in P^{-1}(y)}\epsilon(x)$, where $y\in Reg(P)$ and $\epsilon(x)$ is $\pm 1$ if $P$ preserves resp. reverses the orientation in a neighbourhood of $x$. Then, if $d$ is even, $P$ is not surjective, so $degP=0$. If $d$ is odd, then I choose $y\in Reg(P)$, and I know that, if $x\in P^{-1}(y)$, $P'(x)$ is not $0$ and so it is positive or negative if $P$ preserves or reverses the orientation. Intuitively, I can see that the statement is true, but I can't prove it properly.

Comment: How do you define the degree for a map between noncompact manifolds?

Comment: This is OK for *proper* maps.

Comment: @user72694: In fact we're considering a polynomial of degree $d>0$, which is a proper map. You're right, I should have written it.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: I've defined the degree of a smooth and proper map for noncompact manifold taking the compact support cohomology groups.

Comment: @Claretta Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wait long enough the polynomial becomes monotone and eventually overcomes all local extrema. For odd degree, it tends to $\epsilon\infty$ when $x\to\infty$ where $\epsilon$ is the sign of the leading coefficient; and to $-\epsilon\infty$ when $x\to-\infty$.  Then the inverse image of a sufficiently large $x$ will contain only one point. Therefore the degree is $\pm 1$ and there is no cancellation (geometric degree equals algebraic degree at such a point).